# In which city you are?

Tags: lateral-thinking

Suppose, you are standing in a place, from where-

you can see in the east 6 floored building.

you can see in the west 5 floored building.

you can see in the north 14 floored building.

you can see in the south 9 floored building.

Now your task is to find out in which city of **Bangladesh** you are?

(EXPLANATION IS NECESSARY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it ?

> [Feni](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feni_District)
>
> F - 6 th letter of English alphabet.
> E - 5 th letter of English alphabet. 
> N - 14 th letter of English alphabet. 
> I - 9 th letter of English alphabet.